# Violin plots are not shown correctly in d3.js app

Tags: javascript, d3.js, violin-plot

I accomodated the code for drawing the violin plots from here:

http://bl.ocks.org/asielen/1a5e8d77ae8feb464167

In my `React` app and everything is working fine except for `Violin plot` and `Bean plot` which look very wrong:

[image]

The code for setting the charts up:

```
plotSelected = (e) => {
  let id = e.target.id;
  ...
  ...
} else if (id === "violin-plot-unbound") {
  violinPlot.violinPlots.show({reset:true,clamp:0});
  violinPlot.boxPlots.show({reset:true,   
showWhiskers:false,showOutliers:false,boxWidth:10,lineWidth:15,colors: 
 ['#555']});
  violinPlot.notchBoxes.hide();
  violinPlot.dataPlots.change({showPlot:false,showBeanLines:false});
} else if (id === "violin-plot-clamp") {
    violinPlot.violinPlots.show({reset:true,clamp:1});
    violinPlot.boxPlots.show({reset:true, 
 showWhiskers:false,showOutliers:false,boxWidth:10,lineWidth:15,colors:['#555']});
  violinPlot.notchBoxes.hide();
  violinPlot.dataPlots.change({showPlot:false,showBeanLines:false});
 ...
 ...
}
```

`plotSelected()` function is triggered by button clicks in the `render()` method.

The other charts look perfect, so somehow only these two got messed up, so I guess it needs to be fixed within the `distrocharts.js`, and not really in my `React` code. I think it is `violinPlots.show({reset:true,clamp:0})` function which points to `violinPlots.change` where we can see `violinPlots.prepareViolin()` on line `616` of the `distrocharts.js`. From there I am having trouble figuring out how to fix it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the old code (from the previous version of the `distrochart.js`) for the `prepareViolin()` and it started to work. So, suggestion 'please, use the newest version' on the page probably should not be followed as long as working violin plots are needed.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the `clamp` option for the violin. It should be set to `-1`.